# ButtonColumn event handlers for dynamically generated DataGrid table (ASP and C#)

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a page where the user selects from several fields, then a query is made to a database to generate a table where the number of rows is variable. I want to make a column on the left of this table that has an "Edit" button in each cell so that the user can then edit the row in which the edit button they clicked is situated. I can generate the table and buttons, but I don't know how to handle the click event. If possible, I'd like for everything to be handled with ASP and the code behind.

Here is the ASPX code where the table is populated:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="tblResults" runat="server" OnItemCommand="btnEdit_Click"></asp:DataGrid>
```

To add the column containing the edit buttons, I use the following C# code where dt is the datatable that contains the results of the database query:

```
tblResults.DataSource = dt;
AddBtnCol(tblResults);
tblResults.DataBind();

public void AddBtnCol(DataGrid dt)
{
    var btnCol = new ButtonColumn();
    btnCol.CommandName = "btnEdit_Click";
    btnCol.Text = "Edit";
    btnCol.ButtonType = ButtonColumnType.PushButton;

    tblResults.Columns.Add(btnCol);
}

protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Don't know what to do
}
```

I'm unsure how to use the event handler, and any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using a GridView? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05yye6k9(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yes, but then once I do that, how do I capture the event when the user clicks the buttons?

Comment: You will probably just want to use the built-in row editing support. There are a couple of events you may want to wire up:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating(v=vs.100)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleting(v=vs.100)

Comment: Thank you for the help, it works now. For anyone wondering, I got rid of the method AddBtnCol and simply added AutoGenerateEditbutton="true" OnRowEditing="btnEdit_Click" with the GridView line in the .aspx